# 100vh flex-item is not full height

Tags: css, flexbox, bulma

I am trying to split the viewport into two equal divs that are full height. I am using Bulma, but I suspect my issue isn't related to that.

**HTML**

```
<div class="columns">
  <div class="column is-flex is-flex-centered is-blue is-full-height">
    <h1>Blue</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="column is-flex is-flex-centered is-red is-full-height">
    <h1>Red</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.is-flex {
  display: flex;
}

.is-flex-centered {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.is-blue {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.is-red {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.is-full-height {
  height: 100vh;
}

html,body {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

This nearly works, but there's a little bit of white space left at the bottom:

[image: screenshot]

Here is a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Ciwan/pen/JVRaMV) too.

Comment: `.columns { margin-top: -.75rem; }` from the bulma CSS is the culprit …

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to user 04FS, once I knew it was a Bluma issue, I went and read the docs on there.

I saw the class `is-gapless`, so I tried that, and it works. That got rid of the gap. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

add following style

```
.columns { margin:0 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you please add Body , HTML height 100% just like below:

```
html,body {
  height: 100%;
}
```